# How to recover from two queries stuck in kill state causing all the database to not respond?

Tags: mysql, innodb

During a INSERT INTO new_table (f1, f2, ..., fn) (SELECT f1, f2, ..., fn FROM table) I clicked the new_table in php-myadmin which ran a simple `SELECT * FROM new_table LIMIT 0, 30` which ofcourse couldn't be completed because new_table was not ready.

I tried Killing the query, but it just kept itself in `Kill` state and therefore I assume it caused some sort of rollback in `new_table`.

The copy data query is for a 200GB table and was running for about 10hours till this interruption (I think it was almost finished). I tried to also kill that query thinking it will free things up, but again it got stuck.

I'm seeing this in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATS`

```
    ---TRANSACTION 5254EC173, ACTIVE 39375 sec rollback
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
ROLLING BACK 4169557 lock struct(s), heap size 371276216, 34345786 row lock(s), undo log entries 26939759
```

Is there anything I can do? Any time estimation? Will it try to rollback the whole table and then try to return that whole data? Will it try to use diskspace for all these operations? Is there anything to avoid the lock? would it be a good idea to do `mysql restart` or will this just start the operation over again?

Comment: Before you make any hasty actions like restarting the service, I suggest you calm down and wait for some answers here. The rollback is probably going to take a few hours, probably 10 or even more. It could even be days. But restarting the service will probably cause even more delay.

Comment: Thanks for that, will wait. Does it even make sense that the simple select query from new_table caused such a bad situation?

Comment: I don't think that was the cause.

Comment: And no simple way to restart MySQL while saying "Don't Rollback" ?

Comment: Well, no. You killed the query, there is no "Unkill" as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Please seem my answer to your other similar question involving `innodb_force_recovery = 4` https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53355/30545