# How to copy a table in a production server without WRITE lock and without writing to a file

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm trying to copy a table in a production table. When I'm performing on InnoDB tables:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (SELECT * FROM table)
```

I have a write lock on table. Is it possible to avoid this lock? I am aware there is a solution to write to a file, but due to disk space limitation, I would have to pass on that solution. Also, are there any flags I might be able to add that will make it possible to kill the query during execution without performing rollback?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean you have a "read lock on the table" (you can't write, also known as shared locks). InnoDB writes like yours create read locks (writes have to wait). Reads can work continue without problem. Be careful with the terminology, a write lock is an "exclusive lock".

You can avoid most of the lock problems if you avoid the extra locks that innodb sets because of the statement based replication:

```
binlog-format = ROW
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2
```

Be careful, because if the server is a master, or if you need point in time recovery, in certain cases it may create inconsistences. It also changes the locking logic, so be careful, as it may change the application behaviour. However, if you are not using replication or it is a development database, it will be safe. With this, you will be able to update and insert new records on the table at the same time the command runs.

The second part (kill the query without doing a rollback) is not possible for InnoDB due to internal consistency requirements (atomicity of transactions). However, there are several tricks to overcome it. One is to restart the server with innodb_force_recovery = 4 and then drop the table. A better approach would be to do the copy in chunks - a tool like [pt-archiver](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-archiver.html) with the --no-delete option, which allows you to copy in several transactions controlling the impact on the server (by the way, probably solving your first problem, too). The tool is a free and open source perl script, easy to use.

Comment: "*InnoDB writes like yours create read locks (writes have to wait)*" - are you sure about that? I thought with InnoDB readers would never block writers (and vice versa).

Comment: I should just change that in my.cnf? Is it possible to take effect without restart of mysql?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Readers never block writer. Writers (like this case) block other writers-that is a shared aka read lock. A read lock is a lock that prevents writers to execute. Please be careful with the vocabulary. BTW, readers may sometimes block writers in very specific cases due to metadata locks, but that is another story.

Comment: But the statement never writes to *table*, only to *new_table* and the question says "*I have a write lock on **table***" (not *new_table*). And I'm surprised that a simple insert would block other inserts or updates - I assumed MySQL would use row-level locks

Comment: @Noam, technically you can do it in a hot way (dynamically). But reducing the tx_isolation requires changing the binlog_format to take effect, and changing the binlog_format while the server is running is a potential source of problems. I do not recommend it for a production server, but that depends on how feasible is to restart your server (you seem to be experiencing problems right now).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in fact, InnoDB, well configured does never lock the table, but many people run it with the default, over protective settings that just for the sake of STATEMENT-BASED REPLICATION, it sets a single row lock on every row (not a table lock), plus a lock on the gaps (next-key-locking) for certain operations like INSERT ... SELECT. EDIT: Oh, no, you are right- "table" should not be locked, only new_table.

Comment: While this was running, INSERT/UPDATE queries on `table` didn't get stuck on `waiting for table level lock` but also didn't finish and just got killed by max timeout. SELECT queries ran just fine. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Noam Yes, I suppose you are using 5.1 instead of a more recent version with better auto locking behaviour. In that case, my solution above still applies. If you are using 5.0 or lower, that won't work.

Comment: I'm using 5.5.1 and innodb_ver 1.1.8. So you assume changing that lock behavior make allow INSERT/UPDATE queries to perform reasonably during such a copy?

Comment: @Noam I have tested it, and [several people agree with me](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/12/insert-into-select-performance-with-innodb-tables/), but I cannot give guarantees without testing your particular conditions. Always test things yourself, specially things that strangers say on internet. 5.5.1 is practically 5.1.X, so I wasn't that wrong :-) Recommend thinking about a more recent 5.5.X version in the future if your operational environment allows it.